# Joining through other models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 4 models.  `Factory`, `Car`, `Driver` and `Config`.

`Factory`s have `Car`s. A `Config` belongs to both a `Factory` and a `Car`.  A `Driver` belongs to a `Car` only, but, due to that association, I want them to also belong to the `Factory`.

Essentially, I want a query to find all `Config`s for a particular driver.  That is, `Config`s belonging to all `Car`s that the `Driver` drives, and all the `Factory`s that the `Driver` is related to through `Car`s.

Here are how the relations are set up:

```
Factory.hasMany(Config);
Factory.hasMany(Car);

Car.belongsToMany(Driver, { through: 'CarDrivers' });
Car.hasMany(Config);
Car.belongsTo(Factory);

Driver.belongsToMany(Car, { through: 'CarDrivers' });

Config.belongsTo(Car);
Config.belongsTo(Factory);
```

I want a query such that:

```
const configs = await Config.findAll({
  where: { relatedUserId: ?? },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Include the Models in which you want to "Search".
So in your case something like:

```
const configs = await Config.findAll({
  where: { relatedUserId: 1 }, //searches in Config  
  include: [{
  model : Driver,
  where : { someId: 1}//searches in Driver
},
{
 include: Driver,
 through:{
 where: { CarId: 1} // searches "through" n:m Table
}
},
include:[
 all : true // includes ALL models which are Associated to Config
]
]
});
```

This are some Cases to Include Associated Models and search in them with where.
You may have to change it to work for your Models because I now didnt pay Attention how you Associated your Models.
Check out for more Infos their Docs:
http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/querying/#relations-associations